# Mac Mini mid-2011 with 10.9.3 consistently losing bluetooth connectivity

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, mac-mini, mouse

Several times a day Mac Mini (mid-2011 model) with OS X 10.9.3 losing keyboard and mouse connection. Batteries are fresh, showing level between 73 and 100%. If I'm pressing power button on the keyboard, and clicking with a mouse, and about 30-40 seconds it connects back again. But this if very frustrating, as it happens several times every day for at least couple weeks already.

What could be a cure? Or what should I do to diagnose it further?

Comment: do you have other BT devices in vicinity that are paired with your computer?

Comment: Yes, there is a trackpad. Also gets disconnected, same as keyboard and mouse. Theoretically iPhone is in vicinity of the desk as well, and could count as a bluetooth device, although I don't remember if I ever paired it with the computer.

Comment: It is very difficult to help you without more data. Could you open Console in your utility folder and look for the time stamp when it happened then copy and paste some 20 lines in here.

Comment: Here is what is in Console when all bluetooth connections lost:
6/17/14 8:29:54.000 AM kernel[0]: [AppleMultitouchDevice::willTerminate] entered
6/17/14 8:29:54.000 AM kernel[0]: [AppleMultitouchDevice::stop] entered
6/17/14 8:29:54.771 AM loginwindow[85]: Preferred Localizations total: 1 contents (
    English
)